# Return 'X-WP-Total' from headers in response

Tags: javascript, rest-api

I'm wondering if it's yet possible to get the value of 'X-WP-Total' in the api response.

Here is my request - 
`axios.get(${url}/wp-json/wp/v2/media?per_page=100&mime_type=image/jpeg).then(response => this.photo = response.data);`

which successfully returns all the images from the media library and stores them in an object named photo.

I can see the header value of 'X-WP-Total' in Postman, and I am hoping to return that value without having to create a custom endpoint, or touch the theme file

Comment: If you can see those headers in postman then Axios will be getting them too, you just need to inspect the `response` object to see where Axios stores response headers

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you can access those headers with `response.header`, but not all headers are available publicly unless exposed manually. In your case, to access `X-WP-Total` by the client, you need to set the [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header on your server:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total
```